# Goggle Sheets: How can I build a range from column headers strings instead of the generic column label?

Tags: google-sheets

I have the query: =COUNTIF(Permits!I:I,A2)

I's column header is "Value_1"

How can I make this query dynamic so regardless of the column position of "Value_1" I will get the same output? For instance, if "Value_1" moved from I to B, I'd still receive the exact same output.

Comment: Can you share a public copy of the sheet to see how is it?

Answer (score 0):

One way is by using match and offset:

```
=countif(offset(Permits!A2:A,0,match(B2,Permits!1:1,0)-1),A2)
```

Permits:

[image]

Sheet containing formula:

[image]

**Note**

Excel's [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/offset-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66?ui=en-us&rs=en-gb&ad=gb) for Offset says

```
If height or width is omitted, it is assumed to be the same height or width as reference.
```

I can't find the equivalent statement in the Google Sheets documentation, but it obviously works the same way.